# Does a compact nonflat surface without conjugate points have ergodic geodesic flow?

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, riemannian-geometry

I read this as a conjecture in the paper by Ballmann-Brin-Burns, titled "On Surfaces with No Conjugate points" JDG 25(249-273), 1987.

What is current status of this conjecture?

Comment: see http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1309.6539 for a recent partial result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an open question. Actually it is still not known if a compact non-flat surface with non-positive curvature has an ergodic geodesic flow (with respect to the Liouville measure).

Answer (score 8):

> [PDF download of cited [BBB87] *J. Diff. Geom.* 1987 paper](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/archiv/JDG87_NoConjugate.pdf).

I cannot resist posting their $6$-legged dinosaur(?) Fig.2:

---

[image: Fig2]

---

> "[W]e arrange that
>   the geodesic $\gamma_0$
>   passing through the centers of the caps is positively and
>   negatively asymptotic to closed geodesics $\sigma_{+}$ and $\sigma_{-}$
>   which do not meet the caps (see Figure 2).